# Which protocol (AMQP or MQTT) should I use with RabbitMQ for internal communication among microservices?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp, messagebroker

I need help on following:

I want to use RabbitMQ message broker for internal communication among microservices. For example shopping cart, order, product, payment etc.

1. Can I use AMQP for internal communication among microservices &
   MQTT for push notification to mobile & web browser?
2. Can I use both AMQP & MQTT with RabbitMQ at the same time or only one can be used not both?

Comment: I would start with ampq, that should covers your need,